# rails instance variables when importing from CSV

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rake

The following rake task runs perfectly

```
  task :load_scadenze_data  => :environment do
    require 'csv'

    CSV.foreach("_private/scadenze.tsv", :col_sep => "\t", headers: true) do |row|

      begin
       @supplier =  Supplier.find_by_code(row[2])
       @scadenza = row[0].to_date
       if (@scadenza <= Date.today)
         @cweek_payment = 0
       else
         @cweek_payment = @scadenza.cweek
       end
       Scadenza.create(
          :data_scadenza  => row[0],
          :supplier_id => @supplier.id
       )
      rescue StandardError => e
        puts "Error importing row because '#{e.message}'"
        puts row
      end
    end
  end
```

However when transforming this into a model method,

```
def self.import(file)
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|

  begin
   @supplier =  Supplier.find_by_code(row[2])
   @scadenza = row[0].to_date
   if (@scadenza <= Date.today)
     @cweek_payment = 0
   else
     @cweek_payment = @scadenza.cweek
   end
   Scadenza.create(
      :data_scadenza  => row[0],
      :supplier_id => @supplier.id
   )
  end   
end
```

The records are not importing because
`Error importing row because 'Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id'`

So somehow the rails framework is behaving differently.  What is a proper way to handle the model method?

Comment: I don't think you can use instance variables in class method this way... Try converting your variable names by removing `@`. Would that help?

Comment: In both cases instance variables seem unnecessary. Local variables should do.

Comment: I tried converting without the `@` and it leads to the same result

Comment: Check if `@supplier` is set properly, I guess it's not.

Comment: From the source code it looks like it fails, because for some `Supplier` is not found, if you would like to create `Supplier`'s that  don't exist for specified `code`, you can try replacing `Supplier.find_by_code(row[2])` to something like `Supplier.where(code: row[2]).first_or_create`

Comment: @PawełDawczak  When I load the file via the rake task, all the variables are being handled properly...  Supplier is there...

Comment: Hmm.. the error message stays "Called id for nil", and the only part of your script trying to call `id` on any object, is `@supplier.id`, which means, at that point, some `@supplier` is `nil`, thus - it's not found (`Supplier.find_by_code(row[2])` returns `nil`). Maybe you're running the `rake` task in different environment, so in its database all the `Supplier`s are persisted correctly?

Comment: One more thing, in your "rake" version of script, you're parsing CSV - `CSV.foreach("_private/scadenze.tsv", :col_sep => "\t", headers: true)`, but in your "model" version, there is lack of `:col_sep` option - maybe it wrongly decodes CSV, and it has invalid value stored in `row[2]` so it can't find proper `Supplier`?

Comment: @PawełDawczak Bingo!  That was it, the column seperator.  And I have not invoked an instance variable `supplier =  Supplier.find_by_code(row[2])`

Comment: Ok, I'll create answer then! Glad to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your "rake" version of script, you're parsing CSV:

```
CSV.foreach("_private/scadenze.tsv", :col_sep => "\t", headers: true)
```

but in your "model" version, there is lack of `:col_sep` option - maybe it wrongly decodes CSV, and it has invalid value stored in `row[2]` so it can't find proper `Supplier`?